# How I can decrease and make better my ugly JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I tried to use `$(this).next()` to give control to closest siblings. But in this scope next sibling hasn't seen. If I use `.each()` function, the action  apply to all elements in array, but they executed at the same time. I want see each animation are played, after another animation has done. I thinking to use `.on()` and `.trigger()` functions but I don't have ideas how I can implement them.

```
$('h1.main-logo-text').show().letterfx({
    "fx":"grow",
    "element_end":"destroy",
    "backwards":false,
    "timing":100,
    "fx_duration":"1000ms",
    onElementComplete: function(){
        $('#logoText1').show().letterfx({
            "fx":"grow",
            "element_end":"destroy",
            "backwards":false,
            "timing":100,
            "fx_duration":"1000ms",
            onElementComplete: function(){
                $('#logoText2').show().letterfx({
                    "fx":"grow",
                    "element_end":"destroy",
                    "backwards":false,
                    "timing":100,
                    "fx_duration":"1000ms",
                    onElementComplete: function(){
                        $('#logoText3').show().letterfx({
                            "fx":"grow",
                            "backwards":false,
                            "timing":100,
                            "fx_duration":"1000ms",
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a single function to call for each element; use [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise) to perform next animation when previous animation is complete

```
var elems = ["h1.main-logo-text", "#logoText1", "#logoText2", "#logoText3"];

function fx() {
  return this.show().letterfx({
    "fx":"grow",
    "element_end":"destroy",
    "backwards":false,
    "timing":100,
    "fx_duration":"1000ms"
  }).promise("fx")
}

$({}).queue("_fx", $.map(elems, function(el) {
  return function(next) {
    fx.call($(el)).then(next)
  }
})).dequeue("_fx").promise("_fx")
.then(function() {
  console.log("complete")
})
```